# Web crawler needed

Tags: web-crawler

Does anybody know where I can get a free web crawler that actually works with minimal coding by me?

I've Googled it and can only find really old ones that don't work or openwebspider which doesn't seem to work.

Ideally I'd like to store just the web addresses and which links that page contains.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend writing one from scratch. You can use the time you spend searching for the crawler to write one.

Comment: +1. I don't think there's such thing as minimal coding in this (any?) area as every web crawler is subtly different.

Comment: i dont think i have the coding ability, i only have a bit of experience in c++ and i need to have it start crawling in three days max so i dont have the time.

Comment: now writing my own crawler, hope this works

Comment: @nighcoder1: Good choice. Its bound to work cuz if you have have any trouble with any part of it the community will the happy to help you. All the best :)